# How does one know if the Mail app on OSX is using SSL to connect to your email account or not?

Tags: macos, ssl, apple-mail

I set up an email account, which is supposed to use SSL. But while setting it up Mail said that it "Could not send the password securely" to the server, and that If I send the password other people can see it. I clicked ok, because otherwise I can't setup my mail account.

After that I went to Accounts, and looked at the settings, and it is set to use SSL. But because it couldn't send the password securely the first time, does it mean that EVERY time its going to send the password insecurely, even though the setting is set to use SSL and PORT 993 ?